# UIViewController blank in portrait mode, but subviews are visible in landscape mode?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

A very strange thing happened. I created a UIViewController in IB and used

```
detailController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("detailView")
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailController!, animated: true)
```

to reveal the view. But the strange thing is that it presented a blank screen in portrait mode, and a correct view in landscape mode, as the screenshots shows

I tried

```
self.presentViewController(traceInfoController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and it didn't help either.

My codebase is relatively large and I have already commented out all the codes for orientation adapting.

Any ideas how such thing happens and how to correct it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you use size classes?

Comment: Have you applied proper constraints ?

Comment: If you do use size classes: Could it be that a constraint is breaking your layout in portrait mode, resulting in a blank view?  You could try to use the xcode interface debugger to see if that sheds any light on your issue (maybe your stuff is there, but off the visible screen, etc.)  Also, maybe deactivate one constraint after the other, testing between each step to get a clue as to what might be causing your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone! I just figured it out!

I didn't remember when I changed the layout mode to (wAny hCompact) in IB!

[image]

Look at the small text in the last line, saying iPhone in landscape! So this is the way to design different layouts for different screen sizes!

To solve the problem, just change to (wAny hAny) then edit.

Answer (score 1):

First, check your XIB whether you have enabled Auto-layout and Size classes or not as shown in following image :

[image]

If you have enabled `Auto-layout` and `Size classes`, then you probably would have to give constrains to your views.

Do one thing, apply some constraints to your one of the view and check it. Be sure that constrains are properly defined.

Add comments in case of any doubt..